# What is the Gardening and Landscaping position on posts generated by ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion

Across the Internet OpenAI’s ChatGPT has gained a lot of attention both within and outside the tech community.

There have been negative impacts on some SE sites, especially Stack Overflow.

How are we dealing with posts that are ChatGPT-generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until further notice we will be [adopting the SO policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/7035983) on ChatGPT posts, which means they are banned for questions, answers and comments.

This is in accordance with the [feedback from Community Management](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/310311) that leaves the decision on the topic to the individual sites as needed. For details on the Stack Exchange position and the reasoning behind the ban on SO, see [the SO Help Center article](https://For%20details%20on%20the%20official%20staff%20position,%20see%20the%20SO%20Help%20Center%20article%20on%20the%20topic.) on the topic.

Please note that due to the newness of ChatGPT, all decisions regarding  the topic are valid for the time being and we will be carefully monitoring both the impact of these posts on this site and the discussions and potentially ensuing policies across the network. Any updates will be communicated and discussed as needed.

Comment: ChatGPT provides answers that are well written and appear to be knowledgeable and correct. But, it makes no claim that they *are* actually correct, and in many cases it blatantly makes up facts that are not true (i.e. it lies in order to provide an answer). Until the product actually claims to give correct answers (as opposed to well-written and believable answers), it would be silly to accept anything it says. (Just ask it, and it will tell you so itself.)