# Please give us the no-AI banner

Tags: support, feature-request

Per [the announcement on network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396626/proposed-changes-to-help-center-articles-to-include-mention-of-ai-generated-cont), we need to specifically request the right banner UI, stating that AI-generated content is disallowed, [which is the community consensus here](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-gardening-and-landscaping-position-on-posts-generated-by-chatgpt).

Comment: We should seek input from the community on this. Have I missed a survey question or is this question to gather consensus?

Comment: @kevinskio that’s only a ping for the Community Management Team as outlined in the linked Meta SE post (second bullet point, bold text): Sites automatically get an “AI needs citation” unless the specific community has a community consensus that forbids generated posts - which we do - then we can get a different set. Going for the former would be misleading. So there is no discussion here. If the community changes their mind about generated posts, then we’d request the default banner. I will add the link in a moment.